# Windows 7 & 2008 does not ignore extra backslash in the middle of UNC path

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, unc

So I have a GED system that store files following the following scheme:

`File_Type\year\month\day\file_name.extension`

and store that path in a DB.

You can choose to store only by month in that case the path would be:

`File_Type\year\month\\file_name.extension`

We didn't realize that while we were on windows XP and 2003 as they automatically remove the extra backslash.

But it seems that windows 7 and 2008 are not. Since we migrate our server and client we have huge issue about this.

Does anyone now if there is a way to tell 7 and 2008 to ignore the extra backslash ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it be better to adjust the database accordingly? Shouldn't be a big problem to replace 
**\\** with **\**... ?

Comment: I have to ask for the thrid party provider to make a developement to change the way he writes the path in the DB (MSSQL2005). The path data is stored as text in the DB.